# React Native Builds not visible in App Store Connect

Tags: xcode, react-native, app-store, app-store-connect

I would like to submit my React Native APP to Apple store. I've uploaded my app through Xcode and also with "Transporter" App. App shows that the build uploaded successfully. But when i checked with my App store account no builds available for submitting my APP for review.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the activity tab on AppStore Connect and make sure that your build was processed. Otherwise, you have to wait until it gets ready.

Comment: Look in Test Flight and see if the builds are there. It can take 20-60 minutes to be available.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've Submitted Many Builds to App store connect, but no builds are available for submitting to approval. Actually I'm waiting around one week after submitting the app to App store. But No builds shown till now.